# Check if values of column A exist in column B?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel sheets.
The first "SH1" contains a column "A".
The second "SH2" contains a column "B".

I want to check if all values in SH1.A are contained in SH2.B at least once. I want to output the value "contained" or "not contained" in a new column in SH1 to get the overview.

The values in SH2.B are manually set while the ones in SH1.A are created with a concatenation using a reference/formula.

Is it possible to do this with Excel's functionality?
If yes, how?

Comment: You can use either the [COUNTIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) or the [MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the following structure, then you can use `COUNTIF` and `IF` as follows in SH1 and fill this formula to the corresponding cells.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(SH2!B$1:B$11,A1)>0, "contained", "not contained")
```

[image: res]

Comment: Please note that the separator sign (here ,) might be different in your local Excel/localization/settings.